# When links are open in new tab from react application different information is shown on all tabs

Tags: reactjs, mobx, react-16

I am stuck in a situation. I am creating a table component in which admin can see all the registered users like
I am using **Mobx** as store

```
 Username      email          phone
   abc        abc@abc.com      000
   bcd        bcd@bcd.com      000
   def        def@def.com      000
```

Here the username are links to user profile which are opened in new tab.
**Problem which I am facing is** when I quickly click on all users names, there profiles are opening in new tabs **but the profile info is getting shuffled** 
**like "abc" profile info is show ibn "bcd" profile, sometimes "def" info is shown in "abc" etc**. I have googled alot but not geeting how to resolve it.

Comment: Please provide some code examples or if you can create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on http://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Actually code in quite big and due to some reasons I cannot provide the code :(